# Only one file with Git submodules

Tags: git, libraries, git-submodules

I use Git to manage my versions, and I have to use a third-party libraries, like gmaps.js for example.

For example, if I use:

```
$ git submodule add git://github.com/HPNeo/gmaps.git webroot/javascripts
```

In my folder javascripts, then I would have all the files from that repository.

I need to add only one file: gmaps.js from the root of the remote repository. And I want to update that submodule, in fact I want to update only that file.

Comment: Unfortunately, submodules don't support that concept.  If you use submodules, you have to take the whole repo, and it must live inside it's own folder in the parent repo.  AFAIK, there's no proposal to make them work any differently in future versions of Git.  Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your reaply. Is any way to do that I want to do? Or I have to update manually my third-party libraries?

Comment: If you you're looking for is to have the versions in your repo track some remote version/branch, no. :-(  The only choice is to update them manually or use a script that would help you update them.

Comment: @jszakmeister I guess you should go for answer here and it should be marked as correct one. Anyway, thanks for explanation.

Comment: If the source repo contained a branch containing only that file, that branch could be used.